# gunicorn cannot find file which has wsgi callable object

Tags: docker, flask, wsgi

In my docker file the command is

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b 0.0.0.0:5000", "run:gunicorn_app"]
```

I have a run.py file in the same level as docker file

```
import os

from app import create_app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ["FLASK_ENV"] = "development"
    application = create_app()
    application.run(debug=True)
else:
    gunicorn_app = create_app()
```

now I get error saying, no module named error.

I am pretty sure before with same code, I was able to run the docker file.

Can someone suggest me what can be done. thanks a lot

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine AS base_image

# RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files to the container
COPY . ./app

# Install dependencies
# using apk to install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update &&\
 apk add --no-cache  postgresql -libs && \
 apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc  musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
 python3 -m pip install -r app/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT="5000"

# Add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b 0.0.0.0:5000", "run:gunicorn_app"]
```

Comment: Please post the exact error

Comment: @NoCommandLine, here it is below, thank you.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'run' `

Comment: can you post the complete dockerfile?

Comment: @Kevin dockerfile added. thanks

Comment: whats inisde the `entrypoint.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the Dockerfile i would say you are running the `CMD` within the wrong folder.

You are copying everything to `/app` this should also include the `run.py` file.
But because you are running `WORKDIR /app` you are already in the `/app` Folder.
So all of the Files are now inside the folder `/app/app`.
And because you are running the `CMD` from within your current Working Directory (`/app`) it's clear that `gunicorn` is not able to find the `run.py` File.

So you just need to change your `COPY` to the following: `COPY . .` and then your docker container should be able to run.

You can check by yourself if you are running `docker run -it <your_container_image> sh` to connect into the container and then running `ls` inside the container.

Comment: Thank you, This solved the issue I was facing.